# Shiny sliderInput keeps displaying decimals

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a slider. None of the base values I'm working with have decimals in them, so I have no idea why this continues to happen. I also have set the `round` parameter within the function as `round = TRUE`.

```
library(shiny)

test_df <- 19:45

ui <- fluidPage(

sliderInput("range1", label = h3("Select Range"), min(test_df), 
            max(test_df), value = c(min(test_df), max(test_df)), round = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But as you can see, when you run it, it keeps showing numbers with decimals in the slider range.

I'm clearly missing something but have no idea as to what it is.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `inputSlider` made 10 ticks on your slider, regardless of whether or not that makes sense.  `45-19=26`, `26/10=2.6`, and we are seeing  `step`s of 2.6 on the slider. We can add a `step` argument to fix the slider so it moves in increments of `1` or whatever you choose.

```
library(shiny)

test_df <- 19:45

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput("range1", label = h3("Select Range"), min(test_df), 
              max(test_df), value = c(min(test_df), max(test_df)), round = TRUE,
              step = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```